# Assign aspecific IP address to an vm

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am creating images of existing virtual machines using following code
`service.createArchiveTransaction(templateName, blockDevices, "Image of " + vm.getHostname());`

I am again creating Virtual machines using this image through API. The Virtual machines are getting created, however the public and private ips that they are assigned are not the ones which I am trying put. Those are either the old ips, or some new random ips.

I use the following code for assigning IP:
`

```
 // Set subnet ID for Dallas 9 
   String primaryBackendIPAddress = "10.0.20.98"; //this ip is availble for user under the chosen subnet
   Component netComp1 = new Component();  
   Vlan vlan = new Vlan();
   vlan.setId(new Long(1229225));// id of vlan associated to the subnet
   Subnet ss1 = new Subnet();
   IpAddress ipaddr = new IpAddress();
   ipaddr.setIpAddress("10.0.253.1");
   ss1.setEndPointIpAddress(ipaddr);
   ss1.setId(new Long(1208349)); // setting id of the subnet
   vlan.setPrimarySubnet(ss1); 
   netComp1.setNetworkVlan(vlan);
   netComp1.setMaxSpeed(new Long(1000));
   guest.setPrimaryBackendNetworkComponent(netComp1);
   guest.setPrimaryBackendIpAddress(primaryBackendIPAddress);
```

`

I want to know if this approach is correct to set private / public ips. If not please advise what other methods we can use to set specific private/public ips while creating a vm.

Answer (score 0):

yep that is the approach, but it depends on the method you are using to create the VM. you need to use the same method as the portal uses which is [placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder), if you are using the [createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject) method it will not work, with that method you only can specify the vlans for fronted and backend networks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to assign an IP during the provisioning process. You can select a Subnet to pull an IP from but you're not able to bind a specific IP while ordering.